# How to loop across this JSON in PHP and get data from it?

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON and I need to loop it and get all the rooms, crew_lines and notes in the same order they appear in the JSON order by Date.

The idea is to use PHP to decode the JSON and Loop across it. Some dates can be empty. I need to save into a table all the info from the JSON. The table contains a field named "type" (Room, Note or Crew ) and I need to save then in the same order:

```
11/02/2020 R room_1 B HALL                    ... empty fields
11/02/2020 C crew_line_125443 saa1 Stagehand - Audio - A1 - Head ... other fields
11/02/2020 C crew_line_183352 saa2 Stagehand - Audio - A2 - Head ... other fields
11/02/2020 C crew_line_268994 saa3 Stagehand - Audio - A3 - Asst ... other fields

11/04/2020 R room_157238 Meet In Show OFC - TB ... empty fields
11/04/2020 N note_217088 My Note
11/04/2020 C crew_line_255945 SAVA Stagehand - AV Assist         ... other fields
11/04/2020 C crew_line_305265 EECD Coordinator - Union Payroll   ... other fields

Other empty dates are discarded
```

Can someone help me?

```
 {
"estimate_num": "82",
"estimate_version_num": "82",
"event_num": "32",
"dateItems": [
    [{
        "items": [{
            "id": "room_1",
            "seq": "1",
            "roomName": "B HALL"
        }, {
            "id": "crew_line_125443",
            "seq": "125443",
            "pos_code": "saa1",
            "pos_name": "Stagehand - Audio - A1 - Head",
            "union_code": "U2",
            "union_name": "I.A.T.S.E Local No. 2",
            "ded_time_hours": "1",
            "qty": "1",
            "start_time": "08:00",
            "end_time": "17:00",
            "st_total_hours": "8",
            "ot_total_hours": "1",
            "dt_total_hours": "0",
            "pf_total_hours": "0",
            "tot_hours": "8",
            "st_rate_est": "97.5",
            "ot_rate_est": "146.25",
            "dt_rate_est": "195",
            "pf_rate_est": "427.5"
        }, {
            "id": "crew_line_183352",
            "seq": "183352",
            "pos_code": "saa2",
            "pos_name": "Stagehand - Audio - A2 - Head",
            "union_code": "U2",
            "union_name": "I.A.T.S.E Local No. 2",
            "ded_time_hours": "1",
            "qty": "1",
            "start_time": "08:00",
            "end_time": "17:00",
            "st_total_hours": "8",
            "ot_total_hours": "1",
            "dt_total_hours": "0",
            "pf_total_hours": "0",
            "tot_hours": "9",
            "st_rate_est": "97.5",
            "ot_rate_est": "146.25",
            "dt_rate_est": "195",
            "pf_rate_est": "427.5"
        }, {
            "id": "crew_line_268994",
            "seq": "268994",
            "pos_code": "saa3",
            "pos_name": "Stagehand - Audio - A3 - Asst",
            "union_code": "U2",
            "union_name": "I.A.T.S.E Local No. 2",
            "ded_time_hours": "1",
            "qty": "1",
            "start_time": "08:00",
            "end_time": "17:00",
            "st_total_hours": "8",
            "ot_total_hours": "1",
            "dt_total_hours": "0",
            "pf_total_hours": "0",
            "tot_hours": "9",
            "st_rate_est": "95.5",
            "ot_rate_est": "143.25",
            "dt_rate_est": "191",
            "pf_rate_est": "418.5"
        }],
        "event_date": "11\/02\/2020",
        "item_id": "dateDiv_1",
        "item_seq": "1",
        "parentValue": "11\/02\/2020",
        "type": "crew"
    }, {
        "event_date": "11\/03\/2020",
        "item_id": "dateDiv_2",
        "item_seq": "2",
        "parentValue": "11\/03\/2020"
    }, {
        "items": [{
            "id": "room_157238",
            "seq": "157238",
            "roomName": "Meet In Show OFC - TBD"
        }, {
            "id": "note_217088",
            "seq": "217088",
            "noteName": "My Note",
            "noteUnion": "U2",
            "noteUnionName": "I.A.T.S.E Local No. 2",
            "noteInd": "0"
        }, {
            "id": "crew_line_255945",
            "seq": "255945",
            "pos_code": "SAVA",
            "pos_name": "Stagehand - AV Assist",
            "union_code": "U2",
            "union_name": "I.A.T.S.E Local No. 2",
            "ded_time_hours": "1",
            "qty": "1",
            "start_time": "08:00",
            "end_time": "17:00",
            "st_total_hours": "8",
            "ot_total_hours": "1",
            "dt_total_hours": "0",
            "pf_total_hours": "0",
            "tot_hours": "9",
            "st_rate_est": "95.5",
            "ot_rate_est": "143.25",
            "dt_rate_est": "191",
            "pf_rate_est": "418.5"
        }, {
            "id": "crew_line_305265",
            "seq": "305265",
            "pos_code": "EECD",
            "pos_name": "Coordinator - Union Payroll",
            "union_code": "EVENT C",
            "union_name": "Coordinator",
            "ded_time_hours": "1",
            "qty": "1",
            "start_time": "08:00",
            "end_time": "17:00",
            "st_total_hours": "9",
            "ot_total_hours": "0",
            "dt_total_hours": "0",
            "pf_total_hours": "0",
            "tot_hours": "9",
            "st_rate_est": "95",
            "ot_rate_est": "142.5",
            "dt_rate_est": "190",
            "pf_rate_est": "0"
        }],
        "event_date": "11\/04\/2020",
        "item_id": "dateDiv_3",
        "item_seq": "3",
        "parentValue": "11\/04\/2020",
        "type": "crew"
    }, {
        "event_date": "11\/05\/2020",
        "item_id": "dateDiv_4",
        "item_seq": "4",
        "parentValue": "11\/05\/2020"
    }, {
        "event_date": "11\/06\/2020",
        "item_id": "dateDiv_5",
        "item_seq": "5",
        "parentValue": "11\/06\/2020"
    }]
]
}
```

---

Comment: json decode -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php then loop the obj through foreach or for loop to get the desired key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heavily commented the code. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
// bonus code. this will automatically download a xls version of the webpage. 
$export = "export_" . date('mdY') . ".xls";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$export");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

// decode the json so it is php readable
$array = json_decode($arr, true);

// define headers for the table
// "computer_name"=>"human name" ("don't change"=>"change to whatever you'd like")
$headers = array("id"=>"ID", "roomName"=>"Room Name", "seq"=>"Seq", "pos_code"=>"Pos Code", "pos_name"=>"Pos Name", "union_code"=>"Union Code", "union_name"=>"Union Name", "ded_time_hours"=>"Ded Time Hours", "qty"=>"Qty", "start_time"=>"Start Time", "end_time"=>"End Time", "st_total_hours"=>"St Total Hours", "ot_total_hours"=>"Ot Total Hours", "dt_total_hours"=>"Dt Total Hours", "pf_total_hours"=>"Pf Total Hours", "tot_hours"=>"Tot Hours", "st_rate_est"=>"St Rate Est", "ot_rate_est"=>"Ot Rate Est", "dt_rate_est"=>"Dt Rate Est", "pf_rate_est"=>"Pf Rate Est");

// start table
echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
        // could not add these to $headers array as they don't fall within the loop. They can be changed.
        echo "<th>date</th>";
        echo "<th>id code</th>";
        // loop through the $headers using the array value to add to the top of the table
        foreach ($headers as $header => $hdr) {
            echo "<th>" . $hdr . "</th>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    // iterate through $array
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array["dateItems"][0]); $i++) {
        // iterate through the branch ("items") of array if it exists
        for ($i2 = 0; $i2 <= count($array["dateItems"][0][$i]["items"]); $i2++) {
            // don't display blank rows
            if (empty($array["dateItems"][0][$i]["items"][$i2]["id"])) {
                break;
            }
            echo "<tr>";
                // this is the date and id code cells. Notice they are outside of the loop because of the difference format of where the data is sourced
                echo "<td>" . $array["dateItems"][0][$i]["event_date"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . strtoupper(substr($array["dateItems"][0][$i]["items"][$i2]["id"], 0, 1)) . "</td>";
                // loop through each of the $headers only this time we use the array key. This displays the value of the json array.
                foreach ($headers as $header => $hdr) {
                    echo "<td>" . $array["dateItems"][0][$i]["items"][$i2][$header] . "</td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
echo "</table>";
// end table
```